# in c++ how can I find the maximum system date?

Tags: c++, date, time

I'm trying to find the maximum allowed system date in cpp, but I can't find the function to do that...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: err... I want it to be as standard as possible...

Answer (score 6):

Use [`localtime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) function. Pass to it values from `0` to `numeric_limits<time_t>::max()`. For unacceptable values this function will return null pointer. You could use binary search algorithm to find appropriate value faster: O(log<sub>2</sub> N) where N = `numeric_limits<time_t>::max()`.

The following sample uses boost library, but it still platform independent. You could implement the same without STL or boost if it is required.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

bool less_time( time_t val1, time_t val2 )
{
    tm* v1 = localtime( &val1 );
    tm* v2 = localtime( &val2 );
    if ( v1 && v2 ) return false;
    if ( !v1 && !v2 ) return false;
    if ( v1 && !v2) return true;
    return false;
};

int main() {
    counting_iterator<time_t> x = upper_bound( counting_iterator<time_t>(0), counting_iterator<time_t>(numeric_limits<time_t>::max()), 0, less_time );
    time_t xx = *x;
    --xx; // upper_bound gives first invalid value so we use previous one
    cout << "Max allowed time is: " << ctime(&xx) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would depend on the OS, are we using windows or something POSIX compliant here?

Comment: I want it to be as standard as possible

Comment: there is a fundamental difference in the way windows stores it's dates and the rest of the world. It's one of those things that is only answered by operating system documentation.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_date

Comment: let's say that is for a POSIX compliant system